# Como mudar o estilo de um grupo de vertices em JGRAPHX?

Tags: java

Estou trabalhando em um projeto UML e utilizando o JGRAPHX, ou mxGraph como preferirem.
No caso, quando eu tenho um grupo de vértices, é adicionado uma linha pontilhada para marcar que aquele vértice é um grupo.
Como posso mudar o estilo dele como as figuras abaixo?

Quando não é um grupo de vértices:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando for um grupo de vértices:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução:

```
mxIGraphModel model = graph.getModel();
// start to change model
model.beginUpdate();
mxGeometry geo = new mxGeometry(0, 0.5, PORT_DIAMETER,
                        PORT_DIAMETER);
// Because the origin is at upper left corner, need to translate to
                // position the center of port correctly
                geo.setOffset(new mxPoint(-PORT_RADIUS, -PORT_RADIUS));
                geo.setRelative(true);

 mxCell port = new mxCell(cell.getAttribute("label"), geo,
                        style);
port.setVertex(true);
//is not a port!!!!!!!!
port.setConnectable(false);
graph.addCell(port, cell);
//send to back! 
graph.cellsOrdered(new Object[]{cell}, true);
// end changes, generate the events and     update UndoManager
                model.endUpdate();
```

Att,
Alexandre.